# Create a copy of a rectangle in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to make an area, where a small rectangles appear in the places it where clicked. Later on I would try to add an ability to move those rectangles by dragging.

After studying Help, I tried to accomplish this with a `MouseArea` and a `Component` containing a `Rectangle`. Then, with `onClicked`, I was trying to create a new copy of a `Component`, but I failed whatever I tried (`createComponent`, `createObject`, etc.).

What is the correct way of creating a copy of an object in this case?
Am I using right tools for this goal?

```
MouseArea {
   Component {
      id: rect

      Rectangle {
         width: 10
         height: 10
      }
   }

   onClicked: < what? >
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a QML object from a string of QML using the `Qt.createQmlObject()` and set it's x and y values to `mouseX` and `mouseY` :

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {

    id : root

    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 500

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked:{
            var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {color: "red"; width: 10; height: 10}',
               root);

            newObject.x = mouseX;
            newObject.y = mouseY;
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you put the code for your rectangle in a separate qml file say `myRect.qml`, you can create the object from the qml file by :

```
onClicked:{
     var component = Qt.createComponent("myRect.qml");
     var newObject = component.createObject(root, {"x": mouseX, "y": mouseY});
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm trying to keep all in one file so I prefered first solution. I tried similar thing but made it too complex var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {width: 10; height: 10, x: '+mouseX+', y: '+mouseY+'}', parent);

Comment: Milos, try to use "arg()" function instead of direct concatenation, it's more handy.